# alert box in android is not working

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

The code is not working. Please help me. It print the replace all string, but further code is not running.

when I debug this, there is no error in the code. It will show the code of alert box.

```
if(count>0)

          {
              System.out.println("replace all string name ");
                 // final Intent intent_ul=new Intent(this, UploadExcel.class);
              AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder_ue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);            
                 alertDialogBuilder_ue.setTitle("Alert!!");
                 alertDialogBuilder_ue
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Replace all the data related to this style ? ")

                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                             mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
                              mySQLiteAdapter.delete_style_measurement(style_no);
                              Log.d("","yes click");
                              count=0;
                              mySQLiteAdapter.close();

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            Log.d("","No click");
                            count++;
                            dialog.cancel();
                            // startActivity(intent_ul);
                             //finish();
                        }
                    });
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines before the end of **if** condition

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder_ue.create();
 alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: can you explain `AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder_ue.create();` line? what is `alertDialogBuilder_ue`

Comment: alertDialogBuilder_ue is a builder object using which you can create alertdialog, you can't use builder object directly to show the alertdialog.So you have to get the instance of AlerDialog first and then call show() of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
alertDialogBuilder_ue.show();
```

in your code

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code. This code working for me

```
Context context = CurrentActivity.this;
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
ad.setTitle("Application");
ad.setMessage("Do you want to proceed?");
ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() 
{
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) 
 {

 }
});
ad.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() 
{
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1)
 {

 }
});
ad.setCancelable(false);
ad.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code adding `alertDialogBuilder_ue.show();` should make the dialog appear.

By some people it has been suggested that you **have** to use `alertDialogBuilder_ue.create();` to get a handle to the `AlertDialog` that you can then use the `.show()` method on.

Both are possibilities but you **don't have** to use the `.create()` option if you don't need a handle to the `AlertDialog`